# Смысловое единство у однородных членов, соединенных повторяющимися союзами

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении (привожу с контекстом)? И заодно, по смыслу, нужна ли запятая после скобок?

Удобнее, из соображений универсальности, показывать именно зависимость Кv = f(h), а не G = f(h), выражающую функцию производительности (пропускной способности по терминологии для предохранительной арматуры) от хода для определенной рабочей среды. Впрочем, допустимо и то (,) и другое.

Пример про *дорогу, уходящую и в ту и в другую строну*, знаю. Тем не менее, не могу понять, образуется ли здесь подобное смысловое единство...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы обязательно поставил здесь запятую. Здесь и пауза имеется (которая отсутствует у *дороги*), хотя это не всегда аргумент.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Про паузу не подумала.